# how to untar a tarball in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, archive

I haven't found a way to untar a .tgz file. Here is what I tried so far:

When using ZipArchive, you obviously get following error:

```
End of Central Directory record could not be found
```

I also tried using a GZipStream to decompress the file, but sadly, I can only decompress it to a file, which I cant do much with...
Following code is what I used for that:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("C:\\file.tgz"))
        {
            using (var decrompressedFileStream = File.Create("C:\\file"))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(decrompressedFileStream);
                }
            }
        }
```

How should I untar the tarball into a directory?

I'll explain a bit about my use-case:

I have to download a certain npm package (from client's personal npm registry) and do some processing on certain files in that package.

If you need any extra information, ask so in a comment.
Thanks!

Comment: [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/FORMATS.md) will do the job, but I'm voting to close this as off-topic as it's asking for a library.

Comment: Where am I asking for a library?... I just stated what I tried... which is using  native .net core, and looking for a library

If there's a way to do it without the use of a library, I'd be super happy lol

but thanks for pointing me to SharpCompress
Also, edited my original post as to not seem like i'm asking for a library

Comment: SharpCompress was indeed what I needed, thanks!